# ORM: Change parent's "updated_at" timestamps when model gets updated in FuelPHP

Tags: php, fuelphp, fuelphp-orm

Let's say I have a Model_Post that has_may Model_Comment.

Is there any way that the `updated_at` field of Model_Post gets updated every time that a new comment is saved? I checked the documentation for the observers, but I cannot find how to do that in a "ORM way".

This code doesn't seem to work:

```php
class Model_Comment extends \Orm\Model
{
    protected static $_properties = array(
        'id',
        'post_id',
        'text',

    );
    protected static $_belongs_to = array('post');
    protected static $_observers  = array(
        'Orm\\Observer_UpdatedAt' => array(
            'events'          => array('before_save'),
            'relations'       => array('post')
        )
    );
}

class Model_Post extends Model
{

    protected static $_properties = array(
        'id',
        'title',
        'text',
        'updated_at'
    );
    protected static $_has_many   = array('comments');
}
```

I create a new comment using this code:

```php
$comment             = Model_Comment::forge();
$comment->message_id = Input::post('message_id');
$comment->text       = Input::post('text');
$comment->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the way to do that thanks to [Uru's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624673) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26937120/2995613).

This code works now as I wanted; it was simpler than I thought.

Models:

```php
class Model_Comment extends \Orm\Model
{
    protected static $_properties = array(
        'id',
        'post_id',
        'text',
    );
    protected static $_belongs_to = array('post');
}

class Model_Post extends \Orm\Model
{
    protected static $_properties = array(
        'id',
        'title',
        'text',
        'updated_at'
    );
    protected static $_has_many  = array('comments');
    protected static $_observers = array('Orm\Observer_UpdatedAt');
 }
```

And in the controller:

```php
$comment       = Model_Comment::forge();
$comment->text = Input::post('text');
$parent_post   = Model_Message::find(Input::post('post_id'));

$parent_post->comments[] = $comment;
$parent_post->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mucking about with observers, seeing as you want an ORM-centric approach, you can fetch the parent, update its updated_at, then commit both objects to the DB via the ORM.

However, you're not implementing the whole observer config:.  You're missing the property key, and the mysql_timestamp key.

```
// Adding it with config:
// - only needs to run on before_save
// - use mysql timestamp (uses UNIX timestamp by default)
// - use just "updated" instead of "updated_at"
protected static $_observers = array(
    'Orm\\Observer_UpdatedAt' => array(
        'events' => array('before_save'),
        'mysql_timestamp' => true,
        'property' => 'updated',
        'relations' => array(
            'my_relation',
        ),
    ),
);
```

[FuelPHP Observer_UpdatedAt](http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/observers/included.html#os_updated)

Comment: Yes, I know I would have finished earlier if I updated the field manually. But I am trying to learn this framework and I would be happy use all the features.

I omitted the `mysql_timestamp` and the property fields because, reading the source code, I assumed that they were defaulted to `false` and `updated_at` respectively. Is there something I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `relations` property of the observer config you can have the `updated_at` update when relations change. As long as your child model has a relation to the parent model you can add the relation name into the `relations` property and the ORM will do the rest for you when you save the model.

Please see the first paragraph under the code sample in the [documentation](http://fuelphp.com/dev-docs/packages/orm/observers/included.html#/os_updated).

Comment: Hi, but this is exactly what I am trying to do. In my code, the Post model `$_has_many = array('comments')` and in the Comment model `$_belongs_to = array('post')`. Also, in the observer I have `'relations' => array('post')`. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: That looks correct. It could be that you are not loading the `post` relation when you select the comments, that could be causing the parent model to not get updated.

Comment: The thing is that what I want to do is to update the `updated_at` in Model_Post every time a new Comment is created. Right now don't know how to load the relation when I do `Model_Comment::forge()`. Also, it FuelPHP should be able to get that info from the model, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, in that case you need the observer attached to the parent `Post` object and be saving that instead of the `Comment` model. I am not actually 100% sure if the observer will trigger when a relation is changed, but I don't see why it would not.

Comment: Thanks, you put me on the right track. By the way, relations in the observer are not needed if saving the message. Probably because because the model already had the `$_has_many` property (didn't check).

Comment: Glad to help, it's been a while since I implemented this functionality and it seems I need to brush up on it ;)